# How do I get multiple values from a table in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have three tables:

**authors**
<kbd>**id**</kbd><kbd>**name**</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Albert</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Bobby</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Carl</kbd>  
<kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>Dan</kbd>

**authors_musicals**
<kbd>**rowid**</kbd><kbd>**author_id**</kbd><kbd>**musical_id**</kbd>
   <kbd>1</kbd>           <kbd>1</kbd>               <kbd>1</kbd>        
   <kbd>2</kbd>           <kbd>2</kbd>               <kbd>1</kbd>        
   <kbd>3</kbd>           <kbd>1</kbd>               <kbd>2</kbd>        
   <kbd>4</kbd>           <kbd>1</kbd>               <kbd>3</kbd>

**musicals**
<kbd>**id**</kbd>       <kbd>**title**</kbd>      <kbd>**year**</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>Brigadoon</kbd>  <kbd>1947</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>My Fair Lady</kbd><kbd>1956</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Oklahoma!</kbd> <kbd>1943</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd>   <kbd>Camelot</kbd>    <kbd>1960</kbd>

I need to get all the titles belonging to `Albert` (his `id` (1) from **authors** corresponds to `musical_id` (1, 2, 3) in **authors_musicals** which each correspond to `title` (Brigadoon, My Fair Lady, Oklahoma!) in **musicals**). I thought the following would work:

`SELECT title FROM musicals WHERE id=(SELECT musical_id FROM authors_musicals WHERE author_id=(SELECT id FROM authors WHERE name="Albert"));`

This only gives me the first listing. How can I get all three and since these tables are linked, is there a simpler way of getting what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the tables:

```
SELECT musicals.title
FROM musicals 
JOIN authors_musicals ON (musicals.id = authors_musicals.musical_id)
JOIN authors ON (authors.id = authors_musicals.author_id)
WHERE authors.name = "Albert"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use SQLite but I would assume that it's basically the same as using SQL for any other database.  When you use `SomeColumn = SomeValue` you can only have one value on the right-hand side.  Even if your subqueries produce multiple results, only the first will be used because you're using `=`.

You should be able to keep your current SQL structure and make it work by replacing `=` with `IN`, assuming that SQLite supports that operator.  Then you'll be comparing to all the results instead of just one.

That said, I don't think that you should be using subqueries at all.  It seems more appropriate to be using joins there.  Again, there might be some small syntax difference but something like this should work:

```
SELECT title FROM musicals INNER JOIN authors_musicals
ON musicals.musical_id = authors_musicals.musical_id INNER JOIN authors
ON authors.author_id = authors_musicals.author_id
WHERE authors.name = 'Albert'
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the info between tables and get what you need:

```
SELECT title 
FROM authors, authors_musicals, musicals
WHERE name="Albert" and authors.id=authors_musicals.author_id and musical_id = musicals.id;
```

Comment: Right, but his `id` could change if his row changed for some reason, correct?

Comment: Just add one more line with: select title from authors, authors_musicals, musicals where name="Albert" and authors.id=authors_musicals.author_id and musical_id = musicals.id;